# Getting Error "Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite"

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have this javascript file :

```
var blogDirectiveModule = angular.module('blog-directive', []);

/**
 * display-content-attachment directive to display PDF
 * AngularJS binding is not working for the object element in IE.
 * so, this directive is used to create the object element to display PDF.
 */
blogDirectiveModule.directive('tbdisplaycontentattachment', function() {

    return {

        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            console.log("contentFileAttachmentUrl : "+scope.contentFileAttachmentUrl);
            element.empty();
            var objectElem = {};
            objectElem = angular.element(document.createElement("object"));
            objectElem.attr("data", scope.contentFileAttachmentUrl);
            objectElem.attr("type", "application/pdf");
            objectElem.attr("class", "col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12");
            objectElem.attr("style", "height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;");
            element.append(objectElem);
        }

    };
});
```

I have created a jasmine test Spec file corresponding to this :

```
describe('Unit testing blog-directive', function() {
var $compile;
var $rootScope;

// Load the blog-directive module, which contains the directive.
beforeEach(module('blog-directive'));

// Store references to $rootScope and $compile
// so they are available to all tests in this describe block
beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
  // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
  $compile = _$compile_;
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));

it('', function() {

    // Compile a piece of HTML containing the directive

    var element = $compile("tbdisplaycontentattachment")($rootScope);

    // fire all the watches, so the scope expression {{1 + 1}} will be evaluated

    $rootScope.$digest();

     expect(element.find('object').attr('data')).toBe($rootScope.contentFileAttachmentUrl);
     expect(element.find('object').attr('type')).toBe('application/pdf');
     expect(element.find('object').attr('class')).toBe('col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12');
     expect(element.find('object').attr('style')).toBe('height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;');
});
});
```

On Running this I am getting following error :
**Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element**

Please let me know what can be done to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which line is throwing an error? `objectElem = angular.element(document.createElement("object"));`? or `var element = $compile("tbdisplaycontentattachment")($rootScope);`?

Comment: The link to the docs explains why the error is occuring and how to fix it.